# Solr searcher warming

Tags: solr, lucene

I was reading the book Solr In Action and am a bit confused about warming searchers . It was mentioned that

> Solr allows for stale reads if a commit is in progress and the current searcher will not be closed until the new searcher has warmed up .

But a few statements later , it explains about useColdSearcher

> useColdSearcher = false means All actions to solr will be blocked until all the warm up queries have completed
>
> useColdSearcher = true means the new searcher is put into effect well before the warming queries have finished execution .

I am confused about the current searcher, what happens to that if `useColdSearcher=true/false`. Does this boolean value have any effect on the closing of current searcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following is from solrconfig.xml

```
<!-- Use Cold Searcher
     If a search request comes in and there is no current
     registered searcher, then immediately register the still
     warming searcher and use it.If "false" then all requests
     will block until the first searcher is done warming.
  -->
```

So this parameter only takes effect when there is no current searcher, e.g. in  the very beginning. If it is set to true, then this searcher (the very first in this case and is still warming up) will be used to serve the request, but if it is set to false then all the requests are blocked until this searcher is ready (i.e. warmed up).